# Do not process already present data

Tags: python-3.x

I have a folder in which there are some video files. I want to extract frames from the videos but only those videos should be processed whose names are not present in the csv. It should check for the present video file names in the csv before processing the videos

```
def extractFrames(m):
    global vid_name

    vid_files=glob(m)
    print(vid_files)
    complete_videos = get_completed_videos()
    print(complete_videos)
    new_vid_files = [x for x in vid_files if get_vid_name(x) not in complete_videos]

    for vid in new_vid_files:
        print("path of video========>>>>.",vid)

        v1=os.path.basename(vid)


        try:
            vid_name = get_vid_name(vid)
            vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(vid)
        except cv2.error as e:
            print(e)
        except:
            print('error')
        #condition 
        fsize=os.stat(vid)
        print('=============size of video ===================:' , fsize.st_size)
        try:

            if (fsize.st_size > 1000):

                fps = vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)      # OpenCV2 version 2 used "CV_CAP_PROP_FPS"
                frameCount = int(vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
                duration = frameCount/fps
                minutes = int(duration/60)
                print('fps = ' + str(fps))
                print('number of frames = ' + str(frameCount))
                print('duration (S) = ' + str(duration))
                if (duration > 1):
                    success,image = vidcap.read()


                    count=0

                    success=True

                    while success:

                        img_name = vid_name + '_f' + str(count) + ".jpg"

                        success,image = vidcap.read()
                        if count % 10 == 0 or count ==0:
                            target_non_target(img_name, image)

                        count+=1          

                    vidcap.release()

                    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        except:
            print("error")


        print('finished processing video ',vid)
        with open("C:\\multi_cat_3\\models\\research\\object_detection\\my_imgs\\"+'video_info.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
            fieldnames = ['Video_Name','Process']
            file_is_empty = os.stat("C:\\multi_cat_3\\models\\research\\object_detection\\my_imgs\\"+'video_info.csv').st_size == 0
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            if file_is_empty:
                writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerow({'Video_Name':vid_name,'Process':'done'})

def get_vid_name(vid):
    return os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(vid))[0]



def get_completed_videos():
    completed_videos = []
    with open("C:\\multi_cat_3\\models\\research\\object_detection\\my_imgs\\video_info.csv") as csv_file:

        for row in csv.reader(csv_file):
            for col in range(0,len(row)):
                try:
                    completed_videos.append(row[col])
                except Exception as e:
                    print(str(e))
    print(completed_videos[0])
    return completed_videos
```

Suppose there are 3 videos in a folder. Code is successfully run for those 3 videos and their names are written in the csv. Now if i paste video number 4 in the folder then it should process only the 4th video after checking for the video names present in the csv. Currently it is repeatedly processing all the video files everytime the script is run.

Comment: Can you print out the names you get from `glob` and the names you get from the csv and check if they're the same? You seem to be writing the `vid_name` into the csv, and that is obtained by processing the item taken from `vid_files`. So it can't be the same when you compare

Comment: @TheGamer007 yes u r right. It would be really great if you could please help me with what changes shall be made so that my actual objective is achieved? I am getting little confused over here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, inside the `for` loop

```
v1=os.path.basename(vid_files[v_f])
```

Should be

```
v1=os.path.basename(new_vid_files[v_f])
```

Since you are looping over the `new_vid_files` range. Using those indices on the original list will give you unexpected items. Better yet, you can directly use a for-each loop (since you don't seem to be using `v_f` for anything other than list access) as follows:

```
for vid in new_vid_files:
```

And this `vid` would replace all instances of `new_vid_files[v_f]`.

Next, you are using `vid_name` to write to the csv, so you need to perform the same operation for each item from `vid_files` before matching against `complete_videos` while creating the `new_vid_files` list.

If you create a method for getting the video name as follows:

```
def get_vid_name(vid_file):
    return os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(vid_file))[0]
```

Then you can change the list comprehension to be

```
new_vid_files = [x for x in vid_files if get_vid_name(x) not in complete_videos]
```

---

**Edit:** As mentioned in the comments to the other answer, the output for `complete_videos` indicates it isn't being parsed properly. It is appending both the column headers and other unneeded columns. This code will work despite that, but it needs to be fixed. I am not solving it because it is a relatively simple change, and I want the OP to understand what they're doing wrong.

Comment: shall i replace for v_f in range(len(new_vid_files)) with for vid in new_vid_files:

Comment: You can, but you'd also have to replace the usages of `v_f` for the code to continue working. I've mentioned what you need to do just under that in my answer.

Comment: in the get_vid_name method the parameter name should be vid or vid_files?

Comment: It should be a string that was in `vid_files`, as shown in the list comprehension at the end of my answer. Since you made `new_vid_files` using that list, you can use `vid`. If you're going to use that method even in your `try` block, you'd do `vid_name = get_vid_name(vid)`, and completely do away with `v1`.

Comment: can you please check my updated code below. I guess i am still doing something wrong. The code is still processing all videos from the folder instead of the new. Can you please help me identify and rectify my mistake in the updated code below

Comment: Avoid posting code that doesn't work as an answer, you can edit your question and add it to the bottom (without overwriting the previous code). Can you print the contents of `vid_files` and `complete_videos`? That would make things much clearer

Comment: this is the link for the same https://stackoverflow.com/a/56475906/11312863

Comment: This is the output of vid_files : ['C:\\Python36\\videos\\M_1_awjjride.mp4', 'C:\\Python36\\videos\\M_1_cbgcaofz.mp4', 'C:\\Python36\\videos\\M_1_ccyytugc.mp4', 'C:\\Python36\\videos\\M_1_cfcnnjtq.mp4']

Comment: This is the output of complete_videos ['Video_name', 'Process', 'C:\\Python36\\videos\\M_1_awjjride.mp4', 'done', '', '', 'C:\\Python36\\videos\\M_1_cbgcaofz.mp4', 'done', '', '', 'C:\\Python36\\videos\\M_1_acqybirf.mp4', 'done', 'C:\\Python36\\videos\\M_1_awjjride.mp4', 'done', 'C:\\Python36\\videos\\M_1_cbgcaofz.mp4', 'done', 'C:\\Python36\\videos\\M_1_cfcnnjtq.mp4', 'done']

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56474071/edit) to include these details! The comments are not the right place for this

Answer (score 0):

```
def extractFrames(m):
    global vid_name

    vid_files=glob(m)
    print(vid_files)
    complete_videos = get_completed_videos()
    new_vid_files = [x for x in vid_files if get_vid_name(x) not in complete_videos]

    for vid in new_vid_files:
        print("path of video========>>>>.",vid)

        v1=os.path.basename(vid)


        try:
            vid_name = get_vid_name(vid)
            vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(vid)
        except cv2.error as e:
            print(e)
        except:
            print('error')
        #condition 
        fsize=os.stat(vid)
        print('=============size of video ===================:' , fsize.st_size)
        try:

            if (fsize.st_size > 1000):

                fps = vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)      # OpenCV2 version 2 used "CV_CAP_PROP_FPS"
                frameCount = int(vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
                duration = frameCount/fps
                minutes = int(duration/60)
                print('fps = ' + str(fps))
                print('number of frames = ' + str(frameCount))
                print('duration (S) = ' + str(duration))
                if (duration > 1):
                    success,image = vidcap.read()


                    count=0

                    success=True

                    while success:

                        img_name = vid_name + '_f' + str(count) + ".jpg"

                        success,image = vidcap.read()
                        if count % 10 == 0 or count ==0:
                            target_non_target(img_name, image)

                        count+=1          

                    vidcap.release()

                    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        except:
            print("error")


        print('finished processing video ',vid)
        with open("C:\\multi_cat_3\\models\\research\\object_detection\\my_imgs\\"+'video_info.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
            fieldnames = ['Video_Name','Process']
            file_is_empty = os.stat("C:\\multi_cat_3\\models\\research\\object_detection\\my_imgs\\"+'video_info.csv').st_size == 0
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            if file_is_empty:
                writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerow({'Video_Name':vid,'Process':'done'})

def get_vid_name(vid):
    return os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(vid))[0]



def get_completed_videos():
    completed_videos = []
    with open("C:\\multi_cat_3\\models\\research\\object_detection\\my_imgs\\video_info.csv") as csv_file:

        for row in csv.reader(csv_file):
            for col in range(0,len(row)):
                try:
                    completed_videos.append(row[col])
                except Exception as e:
                    print(str(e))
    print(completed_videos[0])
    return completed_videos
```

Comment: `writer.writerow({'Video_Name':vid,'Process':'done'})` should be using `vid_name`, not `vid`. That was the whole point for my changes to your original code. If you change what is being written to the file, naturally the check will break again

Comment: So rest code is fine just vid needs to be change with vid_name is writer.writerow

Comment: Looking at your output for `complete_videos` you are clearly not parsing it properly. It has the column headers as well as non-video strings like "done". Your code should work despite that, but please fix it. Search online and try to figure things out, or open a new question if you are unable to. Please do not continue on this question.

Comment: I updated the code in the original question. Can you figure out what is wrong in that? In writer.writerow i changed vid to vid_name. What else shall be changed? And the Process header has only hardcoded value "done". It was put by a friend of mine may be for some testing

Comment: Is it still not working? Also, please refrain from overwriting your original code! That just makes it seem like you had no problem in the first place. As for the CSV problem I've mentioned, please make your own attempts at it first. It is quite a simple change. StackOverflow is here to help you when you're stuck, not to write all your code for you

Comment: Are the changes in the entire code correct? as it is still processing all the video files and i have been trying to make changes in this code from past many days but stuck still hence i am trying so hard over here today...really sorry about that but did not find any solution hence had to try over today :(

Comment: From what I can see, it should have worked. You can print `new_vid_files` and manually compare it with `vid_files` and `completed_videos` to see what might be the problem. You can comment out the for loop while you test it, so that you stop processing videos each time.

Comment: The contents of vid_files and new_vid_files is the same

Comment: Just delete your CSV file once. Since you used `vid` earlier, the CSV was updated to store the entire path, which is what it returns now. You have to choose one standard and follow that. Either compare path to path, or name to name. Your initial problem was storing names, and comparing to entire path. My changes will make it a name to name comparison.

Comment: This finally worked.....really really thanks a ton brother....u have no idea what u just saved me from...really really thanks a lot:)